# In what cases am I meant to downvote a question?

Tags: support, down-votes

If a question seems interesting to me, or potentially practical, I vote it up and may star it. If it does not (by being outside of my field of interest/competention) I just go my way ignoring it. If a question seems inappropriate/offensive I flag it. If a question seems to be duplicate or better corresponding to another Stackexchange site - I vote to close/move it.

So what's the case when I am logically meant to downvote?

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/842/why-downvote-a-question-or-answer-on-server-fault

Comment: When it shows a lack of effort that makes you wonder how they find the effort to breathe, then you downvote (if you want).

Comment: Voting is a personal thing. We do not all vote (up or down) for the same reasons. Be honest about how you vote, rather than doing so just to get another badge, as some have done.

Answer (score 1):

See the tooltip text on the downvote arrow for guidance:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)